# Four-momentum in particle physics

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, vectors, conventions

I have seen four-momentum defined in two different ways. One is $P =(E,\vec{p}c)$ and the other is $P =(E/c,\vec{p})$. Which one is correct and if they both are then why and when is it more convenient to use one over the other? Here is an example of the two different definitions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/vec4.html

Comment: It really doesn't matter. For most calculations, you'll set $c = 1$ and put it back in at the end, so these two definitions look exactly the same! If you're not setting $c = 1$, I would prefer the second definition, since something denoted by the letter $P$ should just have momentum in its components.

Comment: @knzhou that should be an answer

Comment: With the second definition the units are correct.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the arguments already given (units), the 4-momentum $p^\mu$ is defined from the 4-velocity $u^\mu$ via:
$$ p^\mu = m u^\mu $$
with $u^\mu = \frac{d x^\mu}{d\tau} = \gamma \frac{dx^\mu}{dt} =\gamma (c, \vec{v})$. Hence:
$$ p^\mu = (\gamma mc, \gamma m\vec{v}) = (E/c, \vec{p})$$

Comment: -1: There is no argument about units that settle this because there is nothing to be settled. You seem to arrive at a single expression because you ignored the other choice of units, to begin with.